# Makefile: multiple input files with one command

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a poblem: My source has e.g. group1_x.c, group1_y.c, group1_z.c and group2_x.c, group2_y.c, group2_z.c.

Now my Makefile:

```
all: group1*.o group2*.o
    gcc -o myapp group1*.o group2*.o $(FLAGS)

group1.o:
    gcc -c group1*.c -o group1.o


group2.o:
    gcc -c group2*.c -o group2.o
```

Well, this doesn't work and it obviously cannot work, because there is one output file specified, but there could be ten input files! My question is now: Is it possible, to let gcc make ompile every group1*.c into a corresponding group1*.o file (without telling make, how many fies there are) and then let gcc link the stuff? I guess that's not doable with the *, is there probably somethng like "while"/"for" in make?^^

Thank you already now!

PS.: I've searched for "make", "multiple files", "multiple input", etc., but found nothing, hope that I haven't overlooked anything

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
OBJS := group1_x.o group1_y.o group1_z.o group2_x.o group2_y.o group2_z.o

myapp: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o myapp $^ $(FLAGS)
```

There's no need for the other rules, since Make already has a built-in rule for building `foo.o` from `foo.c`. And it's almost always a good idea to make the target of the rule the file that the rule actually builds (e.g. don't call the target `all` if what the rule builds is `myapp`).

If you want to construct the list of objects automatically (which I don't recommend), you can do it this way:

```
SRCS := $(wildcard group1_*.c group2_*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:.c=.o)
```

Comment: First of all thank you! But I need to create the object files, because I have also an assembly file to link and there must be linked with my own linker script, and (I think) it would be to unclear otherwise. But the second tip may solve my problem, although it's not recommend. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```